# like any in array sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, sql-like

I am trying to perform a findall with sequelize, where i use $like.

Since the strings i need to evaluate with $like are from a form and change, in value or number, i send to sequelize an array.

Therefor, i would like to use $like for all values in my array.

But i couldn 't make it work yet.

```
var conditions =Array[String];
   for (var element in req.query.HotelID) {
     console.log(req.query.HotelID[element])
     conditions.push(
       req.query.HotelID[element]
     );
   }
   console.log('in loop')
   console.log(conditions)

   db.hotelamadeus.findAll({

     where: {$and:{ Name: req.query.hotel, HotelID :{[Op.like]: { [Op.any]: conditions}}}},
     attributes: ['HotelID','Name'],


   })
```

The strings are in req.query.HotelID.

The array conditions is created well.

I want to find the value in my table which map the conditions on the Name and HotelID fields.

So i tried to perform $like $any as i saw in many posts, but i am not sure sequelize can handle it, as it is not working.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a quick utility function that takes the array and column name and loops through the array and combines [Op.like] and [Op.or] for that? If you are using like then you'll need to append % in the desired places anyway so you have a little manipulation to do